# How to interpret こんな中身のない詩を書いてる

Tags: grammar, parsing, definitions

I was listening to 思想犯

> 他人{ひと}に優しいあんたにこの孤独がわかるものか　
> 死にたくないが生きられない  だから詩{うた}を書いている　
> 罵倒も失望も嫌悪も僕への興味だと思うから　
> 他人{ひと}を傷付ける詩{うた}を書いてる　
> **こんな中身のない詩{うた}を書いてる**

In this part, I’m wondering if I should parse the last sentence as:

> こんな中身の(ない詩を)書いてる

Or

> (こんな中身のない)詩を書いてる (can の here be replaced with が？)

The definition of 中身 is:

> 容器などの中に入っているもの

Which I dont quite understand either because its about 詩. Does it refer to the contents of a song (詩) here?

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you intend to make between your two parsings. How do you think the meaning changes between them?

Comment: @user3856370 Hmm, do you understand if its like 中身の(ない詩) vs (中身のない)詩? This part is just weird to me in general because Im not sure about the meaning of 中身 either.

Comment: Yes that's a clearer distinction but I wonder what your problem is about a poem having content/substance? If I said "this poem has no substance" would you understand?

Comment: @user3856370 This might sound dumb, but I wonder if I read it as 中身の(ない詩), it would mean "content's non-exisiting poem" and if I read it as (中身のない)詩, it means a poem that doesn't have content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [こんな(中身のない)詩]を書いてる
> I write such empty poems

中身のない -- there is no content (this is a の/が replacement)

中身のない詩 -- a poem that has no content, an empty poem

こんな中身のない詩　-- such an empty poem

こんな中身のない詩を書いてる -- I write such empty poems.

I guess from reading you dictionary definition you are thinking that 中身 can only refer to physical content (i.e. a poem with no words), but it can be intellectual content, emotional content etc as well.

Comment: Thanks! So here it is の/が replacing each other? Do you think there could be any ambiguity here if we were to only look at "こんな中身のない詩", or am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: The only ambiguity I can see is whether こんな refers to just 中身 or to the whole of 中身のない詩, but the latter seemed more natural to me. Your suggestion of 中身の(ない詩) is grammatical but doesn't make much sense to me: "the content of a poem that doesn't exist"?

Comment: @firuvi If you say こんな中身がない詩, it sounds more miserable feeling and is audible to others, but こんな中身のない詩 sounds more monologue or poetic or narration i this context.